# How to render either a number or a HTML element depending on what a function returns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function `getGameScore()` which either returns a number or null. Then I call it inside my html file like this:

```
<span>{{ getGameScore(game) }}</span>
```

Now I want to change it so that I render the number if a number is returned, or render an icon if it returns null. I tried something like this, but it just returns a string instead of an actual HTML element:

```
<span>{{ getGameScore(game) ? getGameScore(game) : '<i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i>' }}</span>
```

How would I render an actual HTML element in that case?

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? We need this as the answers can differ based on versions

Comment: @Tushar angularjs which is angular1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use ngIf

For AngularJS:

[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

```
<span ng-If="assessmentRequestValue">{{ assessmentRequestValue }}</span>
<span ng-If="!assessmentRequestValue"><i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i></span>
```

For Angular2+

[NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

```
<span *ngIf="assessmentRequestValue">{{ assessmentRequestValue }}</span>
<span *ngIf="!assessmentRequestValue"><i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i></span>
```

For both, [Try not to use function calls in angular template expressions](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:%7E:text=To%20avoid%20issues%2C%20it%20is,pipe%27s%20input%20does%20not%20change) Use getScore(assessmentRequest) somewhere inside your controller to set assessmentRequestValue

Comment: I'm using angularjs which is angular1

Comment: Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

How about using [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive. As stated in original docs

> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element in a secure way

EG

```
<span ng-bind-html="getScore(assessmentRequest) ? getScore(assessmentRequest) : '<i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i>' "></span>
```